# Building CouchDB with build_couchDB

Tags: apache, unix, couchdb, pouchdb, nosql

I'm attempting to build and run CouchDB following the instructions at https://github.com/jhs/build-couchdb. I am able to build successfully, but when I try to run CouchDB I first receive an error about a bad symbol lookup in a crypto library. Every subsequent time I run it I get the following error:

> Apache CouchDB 1.6.0 (LogLevel=info) is starting.
>
> {"init terminating in do_boot",{{badmatch,{error,{bad_return,{{couch_app,start,[normal,["/couchdb/build/etc/couchdb/default.ini","/couchdb/build/etc/couchdb/local.ini"]]},{'EXIT',{{badmatch,{error,{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,couch_secondary_services,{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,uuids,{undef,[{crypto,rand_bytes",[]},{couch_uuids,new_prefix,0,[{file,"/couchdb/dependencies/couchdb/src/couchdb/couch_uuids.erl"},{line,84}]},{couch_uuids,state,0,[{file,"/couchdb/dependencies/couchdb/src/couchdb/couch_uuids.erl"},{line,100}]},{couch_uuids,init,1,[{file,"/couchdb/dependencies/couchdb/src/couchdb/couch_uuids.erl"},{line,50}]},{gen_server,init_it,6,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,304}]},{proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,239}]}]}}}}}}},[{couch_server_sup,start_server,1,[{file,"/couchdb/dependencies/couchdb/src/couchdb/couch_server_sup.erl"},{line,98}]},{application_master,start_it_old,4,[{file,"application_master.erl"},{line,269}]}]}}}}}},[{couch,start,0,[{file,"/couchdb/dependencies/couchdb/src/couchdb/couch.erl"},{line,18}]},{init,start_it,1,[]},{init,start_em,1,[]}]}}

I installed all of the dependencies listed on the [github page](https://github.com/jhs/build-couchdb) as well as the dependencies listed on [Apache's installation guide](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Installing_on_RHEL5). Additionally, I have rebuilt with the option to not strip down erlang/otp

```
rake otp_keep="*"
```

I am running on CentOS 6.6

Answer (score 0):

I ended up not using build-couchdb, but followed the instructions from the [Apache wiki on installing couchdb](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Installing_on_RHEL5). I had to set permissions as explained on the [CouchDB guide](http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/source.html), but it all worked out just fine.

This has been the best way I could figure out how to install CouchDB on Redhat/CentOS RHEL5/RHEL6.